# ClassNotFoundException using Jaxen in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and I need to use Jaxen.

I have created an "Eclipse plugin from Existing JAR Archive" and I have added it in my plugin dependencies'. But running all, I receive a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException".

Where am I doing wrong?

Ps: I'm using Eclipse Juno on Debian Wheezy. The same method with dom4j.jar and log4j.jar works.

**Edit**
Here my Jaxen Plugin MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Jaxen
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.jaxen
Bundle-Version: 1.1.4
Export-Package: org.jaxen;uses:="org.jaxen.saxpath,org.jaxen.expr",
 org.jaxen.dom;uses:="org.jaxen,org.w3c.dom",
 org.jaxen.dom4j;uses:="org.jaxen,org.dom4j.io",
 org.jaxen.expr;uses:="org.jaxen,org.jaxen.expr.iter",
 org.jaxen.expr.iter;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.jaxen.function;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.jaxen.function.ext;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.jaxen.function.xslt;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.jaxen.javabean;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.jaxen.jdom;uses:="org.jaxen,org.jdom",
 org.jaxen.pattern;uses:="org.jaxen,org.jaxen.expr",
 org.jaxen.saxpath,
 org.jaxen.saxpath.base;uses:="org.jaxen.saxpath",
 org.jaxen.saxpath.helpers;uses:="org.jaxen.saxpath",
 org.jaxen.util;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.jaxen.xom;uses:="org.jaxen",
 org.w3c.dom
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the package (org.jaxen) is exported by the plugin.

Open the plugin.xml and go to the RunTime tab.  There is a list of the exported packages for that plugin.  Add any packages that other plugins will want to see and access.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have no plugin.xml. But into the RunTime tab I have org.jaxen as exported package. I edited the questiong adding my MANIFEST.MF.